# Joining tables with ordered substrings

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below tables t1 and t2

t1

```
PL      V
---   ----- 
PL1   CD AB
PL2   AB EF
PL3   CD EF
PL4   EF AB
```

t2

```
V   VA
-    -
AB   1
CD   2
EF   3
```

I would like to obtain the below output. For each V in t1, get from table t2 the first V (ordered by VA) and show its associated VA in table t1.

```
PL     V     VA   EXPLANATION
---   -----   -   -----------
PL1   CD AB   1   AB is first and has VA 1 in t2
PL2   AB EF   1   AB is first and has VA 1 in t2
PL3   CD EF   2   CD is first and has VA 2 in t2
PL4   EF AB   1   AB is first and has VA 1 in t2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation with `keep`:

```
select t1.pl, t1.v,
       max(t2.va) keep (dense_rank first order by va) as t2_va
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.v like '%' || t2.v || '%'
group by t1.pl, t1.v;
```

Comment: It's actually `max(t2.va)`, but - yes, marvelous!